# node-modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker.js 404 Not Found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular5, systemjs, ngx-bootstrap

I have successfully implemented ngx-bootstrap/datepicker in an angular 5 app. But when I try to use the same component and same configuration in myAsp.Net MVC withAngular app, I get the following error.

Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:xxxxx/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker.js

It appears to be trying to find datepicker.js which does not exist.

I have tried adding the following to systemjs.config.js

'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker':
                { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },

And I get this error:

Error: Unable to dynamically transpile ES module
   A loader plugin needs to be configured via `SystemJS.config({ transpiler: 'transpiler-module' })`.
  Instantiating http://localhost:xxxxx/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/index.js

I have tired other variations like: main: 'datepicker.component.js', main: 'bs-datepicker.js', main: 'datepicker.module.js', etc.. 
They all result in the same transpile error.

This is my Systemjs.config.js

```
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/',
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: '/app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
        '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser/animations':
            'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic':
            'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:/ng2-bs3-modal',
        'primeng': "npm:/primeng",
        'charts': "npm:/charts.js",
        'ag-grid-angular': "npm:/ag-grid-angular",
        'ag-grid': "npm:/ag-grid",
        'ag-grid-enterprise': "npm:/ag-grid-enterprise",
        'moment': "npm:/moment",
        'angular2-toaster': 'npm:angular2-toaster/bundles/angular2-toaster.umd.js',
        // ngx bootstrap
        "ngx-bootstrap": "npm:ngx-bootstrap",
        // ng2 typeahead
        "ng2-typeahead": "npm:ng2-typeahead@1.2.0"


    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: 'main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: "rx.js"
        },

        'ngx-bootstrap':
            { format: 'cjs', main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },

        'ng2-bs3-modal':
        { main: '/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker':
            { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'charts': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'primeng': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },'ag-grid': {
            defaultExtension: 'js', main: "main.js"
        }, 'ag-grid-angular': {
            defaultExtension: 'js', main: "main.js"
        }, 'ag-grid-enterprise': {
            defaultExtension: 'js', main: "main.js"
        },
        'moment': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-moment': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
    }
});
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.